# Queue events until ready

Tags: javascript, events, eventemitter

Is there a known way/implementation to queue events until the event emitter signals it is ready?

Something like:

```
init() {
   await sleep(2000);
   this.ready = true;
}

on("event" (msg) => {
  if(this.ready) {
     doStuff();
  }
  else {
     queue(msg);
  }
})
```

I'm sure I am not the first one to stumble upon this problem

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @ChrisG When my server starts up it connects to a queue. In cases where there is already a message in the queue - I get a message before my initialization process is over.